# How to insert multiple attributes to an element node with Xquery?

Tags: xml, xquery, basex, xml-attribute, flwor

How is each individual writer given a distinct attribute, so that one of the [examples](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml) below would have multiple write attribute nodes?

desired output:

```
<writers writer="n"></writers>
<writers writer="a";writer="b";writer="c"></writers>  
<writers writer="z"></writers>
```

**(which isn't valid `xml` as pointed out in the comments and answer.)**

output:

```
<writers writer="Giada De Laurentiis"></writers>
<writers writer="J K. Rowling"></writers>
<writers writer="James McGovern Per Bothner Kurt Cagle James Linn Vaidyanathan Nagarajan"></writers>
<writers writer="Erik T. Ray"></writers>
```

query:

```
xquery version "3.1";


declare option output:method 'html';


for $doc in db:open("bookstore")
    let $books := $doc/bookstore/book
    for $book in $books
        let $authors := $book/author
        
        return <writers writer="{data($authors)}"></writers>
```

Intentionally nested loops.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Any element can only have a single attribute of a certain name e.g. one `writer` attribute.

Comment: was thinking a list was possible

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is e.g.

```
element { 'writers' } { $authors ! attribute { 'writer' || position() } { . } }
```

but it is usually consider a very poor XML style if element or attribute names carry an index, you can't write DTDS or schemas for that and XPath or XQuery selection might get complicated.